Highlight cell if any value matches another column
I have 2 columns in a spreadsheet.  Column A represents a list of body parts, Column B represents a list of Exams.



Column 1:
Column 2:




ABDOMEN
XRAY LEFT LEG


HIP
US ABDOMEN


RIGHT ARM
MR BREAST


LEFT LEG
XRAY HIP



MRI RIGHT ARM



What I am trying to do is highlight any cell in Column 2 if any of the text contains a match in Column 1.  So for example, ABDOMEN in Column 1 would highlight US ABDOMEN in Column 2; MR BREAST in Column 2 would not be highlighted as there is no match in Column 1.
Ive tried several variations of MATCH or COUNTIF, but come up with either no matches, or incorrect matches.  Another problem is some of my text in Column 1 contains spaces, and I would need it to match the text exactly as it shows in Column 1 (ex. MRI RIGHT ARM would be a match; MRI RIGHT would not; MRI ARM would not).
=COUNTIF(B:B,A1)=1

Highlights nothing.

You could try using the following formula in Conditional Formatting --> =SUM(N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&A$1:A$4&" "," "&B1&" ")))) this will highlight --> XRAY LEFT LEG , US ABDOMEN, XRAY HIP & MRI RIGHT ARM or can use =1-ISNA(TEXTBEFORE(B1,A$1:A$4))

Also, =COUNT(XMATCH("*"&A$1:A$4&"*",B1,2))>0.

You could try using the following in Conditional Formatting:


• Using SUM() + ISNUMBER() + SEARCH()
=SUM(N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&A$1:A$4&" "," "&B1&" "))))


• Using TEXTBEFORE() + ISNA()
=1-ISNA(TEXTBEFORE(B1,A$1:A$4))



Jumping the gun here since I don't have this function at time of writing. But in theory (and with peer-testing through @MayukhBhattacharya), the following should work:
=OR(REGEXMATCH(B1,"\b"&A$1:A$4&"\b"))

The word-boundaries should ensure that we do not match any false positives. What do I mean by that: We won't match "US" in "USA" as we are probably looking for exact words and not Kangaroo words or marsupia.
For anyone out there interested; REGEXTEST() is not widely available to the public yet but currently in BETA.
